# Spring MVC Post Request Between Local Aplications

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cross-domain

I am developing a project where we have two running applications on the same device. I am encountering a problem sending requests between these applications. 
One is executed in 8080 and put the other is running in 8081

This is the method that sends the request:

```
public void sendRequest(String device, String status) {

    RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
    messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    rest.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

    if (EnumClass.InputStatus.TRUE.getStatus().equals(status)) {
        setStatus("true");
    } else if (EnumClass.InputStatus.FALSE.getStatus().equals(status)) {
        setStatus("false");
    } else {
        setStatus(status);
    }
    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    map.add("device", device);
    map.add("status", getStatus());
    String result = rest.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/DeviceStatus", map, String.class);
    System.out.println(result);


}
```

This is the method of another application that should receive the request:

```
@RestController
public class DeviceController  {
    @RequestMapping(value = "DeviceStatus", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void ReceiveDeviceStatus(@RequestParam("device") String device,@RequestParam("status") String status){
        System.out.println("Entrou aqui");
        System.out.println("device = " + device);
        System.out.println("status = " + status);
    }
}
```

I am receiving the following message:

```
 2015-04-08 15:39:11.920  WARN 6140 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : POST request for "http://localhost:8080/DeviceStatus" resulted in 405 (Method Not Allowed); invoking error handler
2015-04-08 15:39:11.931 ERROR 6140 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 405 Method Not Allowed] with root cause
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 405 Method Not Allowed
```

And the application that receives the request returns the sequinte message:

```
2015-04-08 15:12:24.555  INFO 7352 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 34 ms
2015-04-08 15:12:24.577  WARN 7352 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported
```

I'm not sending information to any web page , I am using the requests only to send information between applications. Would someone help me deal with this error?
When I use the Requests within the same application , it works right .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your second application, `ReceiveDeviceStatus` needs to return something. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607290/which-return-type-use-in-spring-mvc-in-requestmapping-method).