# JSP page loading with error

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm new in Spring MVC and restful servlet;When I request a jsp page by this url `http://localhost:8080/ES/index` It returns 404 but when I request for `http://localhost:8080/ES/api/foo/` I got result.

MY JSP Page is simple .
Here's Controller , web.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    Controller
    `@RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api/foo")
    public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public ResponseEntity<FindAllEstateQueryJsonObject> findAll(@RequestParam(value = "start", required = false, defaultValue = "0") Integer start
                , @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false, defaultValue = "10") Integer size
                , @RequestParam(value = "type", required = false) String type) {
            // ommited
            return new ResponseEntity<JsonObject>(jsonObject, HttpStatus.OK);
        }`

mvc-dispatcherservlet.xml
`<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.geopart.estate.web"/>


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:org.geopart.estate.resources.messages"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en">
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>`

web.xml

    <web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <!-- Spring Context Param-->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/application-context.xml
            ,/WEB-INF/spring-data.xml
            ,/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!--Spring Listener -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Why would you get something at `/ES/index`. If it's a JSP, it should be `/ES/index.jsp`. If it's a controller, then how is the controller defined?

Comment: Because this:
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>


BUT it hasn't got any different /ES/index.jsp or any other type! :)
Is it needed controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, its because you dont have a request mapping for your index page. You have only shown one controller, which maps the url containing "/api/foo".

```
@RequestMapping("/api/foo")
public class Controller {
```

You need another @RequestMapping for "/index", which can either be class scoped as you have already done:

```
@RequestMapping("/index")
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String homePage() {
        return "myHomePage";
    }`
}
```

Or method scoped:

```
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String homePage() {
        return "myHomePage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/otherPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String otherPage() {
        return "aDifferentPage";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you 
But what my method returns should be  ModelAndView or String?
Could you explain or tell me a ref?

Comment: There's a bunch of different return types you can use, but I think its important to be consistent.  The answer to this question gives you a run down off all the different return types you can use:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607290/which-return-type-use-in-spring-mvc-in-requestmapping-method

Answer (score 0):

What you want exactly is not clear. You haven't mapped **index** to any request mapping like you did for **/api/foo**. If you are looking to use **/api/foo** as **index** page then no need to add **/index** at the end of your url. For that just add **/api/foo** to the list of your welcome files in **web.xml**

Example:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>api/foo</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```