# How to use @ResponseBody to return a map<string, string>?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
public class RestfulControllerImpl implements RestfulController {

  @Override
  @RequestMapping(value = "maptest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public Object mapReturn() {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("name", "test1");
    map.put("sex", "male");
    map.put("address", "1324");
    map.put("old", "123");
    return map;
  }  
}
```

I want to return a `map<string, string>` for the request, and it occurs

> HTTP-406 not acceptable

How to implement the method to return a response body with a map and it shows in like a json object?

Comment: Maybe the accepted answer in the following question is of some use?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607290/which-return-type-use-in-spring-mvc-in-requestmapping-method/18607573#18607573

Answer (score 6):

If your Controller only return json (REST API) then annotate Class with `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`. Then you don't need to add `@ResponseBody` annotation to each and every Endpoint. Since we cleared the problem with missing `@ResponseBody` Below code will do what you want.

```
@GetMapping("/maptest")
public ResponseEntity<?> mapReturn() {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("name", "test1");
    map.put("sex", "male");
    map.put("address", "1324");
    map.put("old", "123");
    return ResponseEntity.ok(map);
}
```

Here `ResponseEntity` is wrapper for Http response. Since I declared here as `ResponseEntity<?>` I can return any Object as json. (It is good when you have return error response as another object) But if you sure that it will only return Map Object you can write it as `ResponseEntity<Map>` (If you have separate error handler)
Hope this is clear.

Comment: I need help in returning Map<Long, Boolean> in the API response. I am getting a Map<String, Boolean> in the response where I am returning a Map<Long, Boolean> from the controller.

Comment: @mantri I may need to see the code first. But as a suggestion, Can't you convert string to data type you from frontend?

Comment: `@GetMapping("/user/getLiveCelebs")
public ResponseEntity<Map<Long, Boolean>> getLiveCelebs(HttpServletRequest request)

{
    Map<Long, Boolean> result = quizService.getLiveCelebs(request.getHeader("Authorization"));
    return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
}`



When I put debug point on result, I see a Map of Long - Boolean. But on Swagger/API Response, its String vs Boolean. Long map keys are somehow getting converted to String.

While the front end can parse Long from String, but it should not happen firstly. I want them to be returned as Long.

Comment: @mantri, According to https://www.json.org/json-en.html, a JSON object is an unordered set of name/value pairs, where name is always a string. 

Hence, it's not possibly to do so because the result will not be a valid JSON.

Actually I bumped into this too :)

Answer (score 1):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "maptest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> mapReturn() {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("name", "test1");
    map.put("sex", "male");
    map.put("address", "1324");
    map.put("old", "123");
    return new ResponseEntity(map, HttpStatus.OK); // you can change status code based on response
}
```

You can set up ResponseEntity details such as body, status or headers.

Comment: I need help in returning Map<Long, Boolean> in the API response. I am getting a Map<String, Boolean> in the response where I am returning a Map<Long, Boolean> from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

4XX is client side error
try add request headers
Accept:application/json

Comment: Looks more like a comment than answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the return type of the function to `Map<String, String>` and adding "produces" to the request mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(path="maptest", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, String> test() {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("key1", "value1");
    map.put("key2", "value2");
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work: `java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity`

Comment: I tested it before posting the response. Using Spring Boot 2.0.1.RELEASE inside a @RestController

Comment: I assume you're using Jackson? It may be to do with what converters Jackson can find on the classpath. You might have pom dependencies which I don't have

Comment: Yes, probably is what you said. I have jackson-core, jackson-databind and google-http-client-jackson2 for JIRA oauth

Comment: This is actually what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

"HTTP-406 not acceptable" mostly deals with content negotiation you can also check headers in the browser when you face this kind of problem, solution can be obtained using Jackson or Gson Dependency

Client Side

```
var jsonData = '{"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonData);
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getJSON",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache:false,
    async:false,
    data : obj,     
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data.name);
        console.log(data.gender);
        console.log(data.address);

    
    }
});
```

Server Side:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getJSON")
@ResponseBody
public  String  mapReturnUsingJackson() throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException   {

    Map<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hashMap.put("name", "County");
    hashMap.put("address", "Unknown");
    hashMap.put("gender", "male");
    String jsonJackson=new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(hashMap);
    return jsonJackson;
   }

   //OR

   @RequestMapping(value="/getJSON")
   @ResponseBody
   public  String  mapReturnUsingGSON() {

    Map<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hashMap.put("name", "County");
    hashMap.put("address", "Unknown");
    hashMap.put("gender", "male");
    String jsonStr = new Gson().toJson(hashMap);
  
    return jsonStr;
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Return map instead of object.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "maptest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public Map<String,String> mapReturn() {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("name", "test1");
            map.put("sex", "male");
            map.put("address", "1324");
            map.put("old", "123");
            return map;
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't work - `"message": "java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity"`

Answer (score -2):

@ResponseBody is use for returning string/json. You might wanted to use model, have a look at this

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html